# Tensorflow gets stuck in sess.run() while making a prediction

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, apache-kafka, cherrypy

I'm using an **ssd** model to make prediction on images using
**tensorflow**. I'm currently on **tensorflow 1.14.0**.

I'm running the code in two different environments. I'm making a
request to **Cherrypy** in one environment and it is working perfectly
fine.

In the other environment, the request is made to **Cherrypy** through
**Kafka** and the `tf.session.run()` gets stuck infinitely and doesn't return any output nor does it raise an exception.

```py
results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
                             feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
```

This line is found in `session.py` package in `TensorFlow`. This is the specific point in code where the code gets stuck

I have not been able to figure out a reason for this anomaly and I
didn't find anything useful on the internet regarding this problem.
Does sending a request through **Kafka** is causing such an abnormal behavior?

Any help in this regard would be very appreciated. Thank You.

The details of my environment:

> CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
>   LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
>   LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
>   LANG=en_US.UTF-8 MANAGERPID=3651 DISPLAY=:0
>   INVOCATION_ID=56bfbab67ced4d1496b1e75a14fb4af7
>   GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu COLORTERM=truecolor
>   ZEITGEIST_DATA_PATH=/home/pandas/.local/share/zeitgeist
>   USERNAME=pandas XDG_VTNR=2 SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
>   XDG_SESSION_ID=2 USER=pandas DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
>   TEXTDOMAINDIR=/usr/share/locale/
>   GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN=/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/a438ce7f_2ce0_4925_a81f_ef228f7d5a94
>   JOURNAL_STREAM=9:71038 TEXTDOMAIN=im-config SSH_AGENT_PID=3796
>   QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1 XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
>   XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
>   XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
>   DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=d47913508d685ac43652dcc65e059d87
>   GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge WINDOWPATH=2 TERM=xterm-256color
>   SHELL=/bin/bash VTE_VERSION=5202 QT_IM_MODULE=xim XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
>   IM_CONFIG_PHASE=2 DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE=session
>   XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
>   GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
>   GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=:1.98 XDG_SEAT=seat0 SHLVL=1 GDMSESSION=ubuntu
>   GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated LOGNAME=pandas
>   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=d47913508d685ac43652dcc65e059d87
>   XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>   XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
>   XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
>   PATH=/home/pandas/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>   SESSION_MANAGER=local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/3691,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/3691
>   LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus